# How to loop throw asp radiobuttonlist and set specific parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, radiobuttonlist

I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488462/asp-net-looping-through-controls-in-a-table) question but it could be deprecated and is not resolve my problem at all.
I consider how to loop throw asp:radiobuttonlist which is already bound with data and set visible parameter of specific item. For example I have five items in a radiobuttonlist and I want to make visible only item 1 and item 4.

Comment: That code isn't "deprecated". Show your attempt and the results.

Comment: ok thanks and the second part of question?

Comment: You know that a `ListItem` has no `Visible` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the items you want to keep, then clear the items and add the stored items:

```
int[] keepIndexes = { 0, 3 }; // item 1 and 4
ListItem[] keepItems = keepIndexes.Select(i => rbl.Items[i]).ToArray();
rbl.Items.Clear();
rbl.Items.AddRange(keepItems);
```

This is the approach if you really want to make them "invisible" since there is no property `Visible` in [`ListItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem(v=vs.110).aspx). But maybe you are confusing it with `Enabled` then this is more appropriate:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rbl.Items.Count; i++)
    rbl.Items[i].Enabled = keepIndexes.Contains(i);
```